Prevent pyglet shapes from blending
I have the following code.
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True)
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

rectangle1 = pyglet.shapes.Rectangle(100, 100, 80, 80, color=(128, 0, 0, 128), batch=batch)
rectangle2 = pyglet.shapes.Rectangle(150, 150, 80, 80, color=(128, 0, 0, 128), batch=batch)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    
    batch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()


Here is the result:

I want to prevent that the color of the two rectangles add. Instead, the whole area should have just one color.
I googled, found the pyglet.graphics module and the commands glEnable(GL_BLEND), glDisable(GL_BLEND), and glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO). All of these do not have the desired effect or any effect at all. I suspect that they do not affect the classes from the shapes library.
I also asked chatGPT, no good results.

Having color with opacity , is this one requirement ?

Yes, I want it to work with all alpha values.

Also, this is clearly related to OpenGL, so why delete the flag?

Since you need to use opacity then you have to custom draw it with vertex , using glVertex2f

Change the color to solid color without opacity then you will be able to achieve this
color=(128, 0, 0)
or you have to custom draw the requirment
fbo1 = GLuint()
glGenFramebuffers(1, fbo1)
texture1 = GLuint()
glGenTextures(1, texture1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, window.width, window.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, None)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo1)
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1, 0)

then you can get output like


Sorry, but if I execute this code nothing happens.

You need to Create vertex I just gave you an example not exact code like this
